# FormType - ManyToMany on himself

Tags: symfony

I try to do a Parents, Children relation on an Entity, but I've a problem when I submit the form. (It's a ManyToMany on himself)

To do it, I've a ManyToMany relation on my entity like it:

```
class Strain
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Strain", inversedBy="children")
   */
  private $parents;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Strain", mappedBy="parents")
   */
  private $children;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->parents = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  public function addParent(Strain $strain)
  {
    $this->parents->add($strain);
  }

  public function removeParent(Strain $strain)
  {
    $this->parents->removeElement($strain);
  }

  public function getParents()
  {
    return $this->parents;
  }

  public function getChildren()
  {
    return $this->children;
  }
```

I think it's okay, I've the foreign keys, an intermediate table strain_strain, with 2 columns: strain_source and strain_target.

My FormTypes:

```
class StrainType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
   * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
   * @param array $options
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
   $builder->add('parents', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => StrainParentType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ))
    ;

  /**
   * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
   */
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Strain'
      ));
  }
```

And the second:

```
class StrainParentType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
   * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
   * @param array $options
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder->add('gmoStrain', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Strain',
            'choice_label' => 'systematicName',
            'placeholder' => '-- select a parent --',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('strain')
                    ->orderBy('strain.systematicName', 'ASC');
            }
        ))
    ;

  /**
   * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
   */
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Strain'
    ));
  }
```

When I send the form, symfony return this error:

> Neither the property "strain" nor one of the methods "getStrain()", "strain()", "isStrain()", "hasStrain()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Strain".

If someone have an idea :/ Because I don't know how to do it.

EDIT:
The problem is in the FormType, because I need a Collection of EntityType, I've do 2 FormType, but I can do it in on FormType and use entry_options to define config of EntityType, like this:

```
class StrainType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('parents', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
            'entry_options' => array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Strain',
                'choice_label' => 'systematicName',
                'placeholder' => '-- select a parent --',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('strain')
                        ->orderBy('strain.systematicName', 'ASC');
                }
            ),
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Strain'
    ));
}
```

Comment: I think parents relation should be OneToMany and childern - ManyToOne. Because single parent, can have many children, but single children can only have one parent

Comment: If I do it I think it works, but in my case, a child can have 2 parents maybe more, and parents can have many children, that's why I try to do it with a ManyToMany relation.

Comment: Then you need to join table for manytomany relations ids. Ex.: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: I've edit my own message, it works